# Extension of a function from N to N to a continuous function in the Stone Cech compactification

Tags: general-topology

Let be $f: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow{}\mathbb{N}$ a function. I need to prove that exist a continuous function $g:  \beta\mathbb{N}\rightarrow{} \beta\mathbb{N}$ such that $g↾\mathbb{N}=f$.

I have thought in the function  $g:  \beta\mathbb{N}\rightarrow{} \beta\mathbb{N}$, $g(U)=\left\{{X\subseteq\mathbb{N}: \exists{} A \in{} U \text{ such that } f(A)\subseteq X}\right\}$, but I could not prove that $g↾\mathbb{N}=f$.

Answer (score 2):

Your choice of $g$ is fine. Let $n\in\Bbb N$. Recall that $n$ is identified with the principal ultrafilter $p_n=\{A\subseteq\Bbb N:n\in A\}$. Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
g(p_n)&=\{X\subseteq\Bbb N:f[A]\subseteq X\text{ for some }A\in p_n\}\\
&=\{X\subseteq\Bbb N:f[A]\subseteq X\text{ for some }A\subseteq\Bbb N\text{ such that }n\in A\}\\
&=\{X\subseteq\Bbb N:f(n)\in X\}\\
&=p_{f(n)}\;,
\end{align*}$$

which we identify with $f(n)$. Thus, with the usual identifications we have $g\upharpoonright\Bbb N=f$.

For continuity and more information about function extensions see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/189155/12042).