# Arrow's Impossibility Theorem and Ultrafilters. References

Tags: reference-request, filters, social-choice-theory

I need some references (far away from Wikipedia) about the proof using Ultrafilters of Arrow's Impossibility Theorem. Online resources are preferred.

Comment: @Norbert’s first link should be [this](http://pleasantfeeling.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/arrowstheorem/), and the second is to a PDF that contains a somewhat different result. The paper linked from the comment after [this MSE answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/35720/12042) contains a proof, but [this blog post](http://algorithmicallyincompressible.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/ultrafilters-and-social-choice/#more-95) does it more neatly. [This PDF](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~robbin/ARROW.pdf) by Joel Robbin is another.

Comment: I wrote up a proof here: http://blog.jyotirmoy.net/2013/10/arrows-impossibility-theorem-and.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no one else has answered, I’m turning my comment into an answer. [This blog post](http://pleasantfeeling.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/arrowstheorem/) gives a reasonably clear version of the proof. [This one](http://algorithmicallyincompressible.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/ultrafilters-and-social-choice/#more-95) is a bit better and has a nice [follow-on](http://algorithmicallyincompressible.wordpress.com/2009/11/05/ultrafilters-and-social-choice-ii/) on the Gibbard-Satterthwaite theorem. [This PDF](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~robbin/arrow_redux.pdf) by Joel W. Robbin at the University of Wisconsin — Madison also does a nice job.